# Online anonymity for a journalist in a dangerous country

Tags: privacy, vpn, tor, anonymity

I am a journalist in a corrupt country. I am concerned that my online usage will allow my antagonists to track me down, and it wouldn't end very good. 
I am aware that I may use TOR and VPNs, and chain them together, to obscure my network presence. 
What else can I do to prevent my adversaries from identifying me?

Comment: This question is very broad. If you search on this site for `anonymity` you might find some directions. Then you can edit this question to be more specific.

Comment: Use Tails and Tor. Check https://guardianproject.info/. Contact civil liberty groups who can help you (over Tor on a Tails-based machine!)

Comment: Also encrypt any kind of important files you have , delete every social/cloud/email account and anything that could relate to you and create new accounts preferable to use disposable email accounts ( just google it )  use very good passwords different for each sensitive account , definitely don't use Windows OS , never talk too much on the phone and don't use sms (the best is not have a smartphone) pay the vpn with bitcoins , learn how send encrypted GPG emails...so much things

Comment: Forgot to say that you should create your new accounts with fake information under Tor/VPN and never under any situation access them without the vpn or your IP will be leaked and they'll know what ISP to go ask information

Answer (score 1):

(**PS**: *This post is just a general discussion. I am in no ways enticing anyone to commit any crime!*)

In order to be anonymous you really have to consider other things too, other than just using some tools while browsing the internet. Tor or VPN might help you to anonymize your identity online but have you considered being anonymous in your real(Offline) life.

Have you considered the fact that social engineering can also de-anonymize you or reveal your identity! 
You just mentioned in your question that you are a journalist in some country and it would end bad for you. I don't know if it is true, but if it was true then you just revealed something about your identity here! I am pretty sure that this website has logged your public IP too.(It's different issue if you are using some proxy or not.) What if someone here on StackExchange had some suspicion about your this particular post and starts an investigation. He/she starts a discussion with you and finally get in contact with you. At last maybe it turns out that this user was one of the guys who were tracking you. (Perhaps one of that guys might have upvoted your question or my answer. :P )

Another *example* could be that suppose you use gmail for sending and receiving emails. Suppose in very begining you accessed your email account without using any proxy. So Gmail knows your actual public IP. The scenario would be something like below:

Scenario 1:

```
You(Public IP)   ---->   Gmail server
```

After some days you read that VPN or Tor will make you anonymous. So you started using Tor or VPN to access your email account. Now the scenario will be something like this:

```
You(Public IP)   ---->   VPN/Tor  ------->  Gmail server
```

Consider that you sent a threatening email to some VVIP. You think as you are using VPN/Tor you are anonymous. This VVIP has some decent friends in all three letter organizations(MI6, CIA, RAW etc...). Now they all are after you. They ask every email service providers to find who is the owner of this email address. The email service provider will have logs containing all the IP addresses you used to access your email. Then they find your original IP that you used in scenario 1. The very next hour you have some guys in black suits at your door.

I just gave an example of an email service providers. Consider the same for online shopping sites.

Suppose you shopped on Amazon to buy something using the same email address that you used to send the threatening email. You used Tor/VPN etc. to connect to the Amazon. It is very common that many users will give their home/company address for the delivery. Now maybe the 3 letter organization guys might ask Amazon to search the user profile for the person who has the email address that was used to send the threatening email. Amazon looks up its database and finds that you live at XYZ street!
Again you shall see your friends in black suits. :P

I know that the above scenarios sounds bit like a hollywood style, but just think about it, they can happen. It really depends how worth your are.(Sorry I don't mean anything to you personally) I mean to say how worth are you to the guys who want to find you. If you are really a worth and if the guys after you are powerful & intelligent, then beware. There could be thousands of ways to find you. If not you they will find some one close to you your parents, girlfriend or even your dog/cat.  On other hand you have to be very cautious about what you do and how you do and not make any mistake.

I am not trying to scare you from being anonymous. Also I am  NOT trying to entice you to do something that is against the law. If you feel that I have said something against your personality in my answer then I can assure you that it was unintentional.

Comment: I suppose the real question is: anonymous to whom?

Comment: @schroeder You are right and as you mentioned that this question is too broad, I agree with that fact too. I just answered more in general, so that others users who are looking for such kind of answers can refer to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One resource I like specifically for journalists is EFF Surveillance Self-Defence (https://ssd.eff.org/en/playlist/journalist-move)
Their resources come in parts, simplified it looks like this:

Threat modelling. -
Who is likely to be interested in monitoring your or uncovering your identity.

How to communicate with others. -
Voice, e-mail, Text Messages, and instant messages.

Protecting your data. -
Encryption, passwords, keys, computers, etc.

Destroying data. -
Keeping it from being recovered by adversaries.

Depending on the threat you face you have a variety of harder and easier options to help protect your identity. It is important to understand who may be after you, so you may better balance the risks you take with value of communicating the information you know.

If your country's government is your adversary you must take extreme and difficult measures to reduce your risk of detection. If instead your adversary is a small group with limited resources and limited technical knowledge you may only need to take some common simple precautions.

In order to understand identity protection you need to think about it from your adversaries perspective. If for example you post to an online website that requires you to have an account and shows your userid with every post you make, and you have only one account on the website, an adversary will easily conclude that all the posts you make are made by the same person. If you instead have a number of accounts on the website and make your posts with different userids, it will be harder for an adversary to conclude that all your posts are made by the same person. Taking this concept to the extreme, if you only used a given user account once to post your information, it would be harder to conclude that any two of your posts were made by the same person.

The scenario I have been presenting is a simplification. If you always had the same IP address, and the IP address of the user was published along with their post, using a different user account for each post would not provide much protection. Additionally using the same writing style in each post, makes it easier for a adversary to conclude that two posts were written by the same person even if userid and IP address are different.

Additional markers of identity include aspects like typical time of day for your online activity. Other identifiers may include references to local weather, geography, sports teams. References that indicate where you are may help an adversary determine where you work or live.

If specific information you wish to share online is likely to attract adversaries, you need to separate your identity from the information you wish to share online. Do not use any existing online accounts when sharing this information. Instead create new accounts specifically for attempting to remain anonymous and use those accounts only for sharing the information that may attract adversaries. Try to make your new accounts as unrelated to existing accounts or services you use as possible. If you create a new e-mail account, do not send e-mail between your new account and any existing accounts. Get a separate mobile phone so you don't accidentally link one of your new accounts to existing home or mobile phone.